# Blazor Web Assembly released App not displaying properly

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I've published my Blazor WebAssembly app as a standalone app. Now I'm running the .exe and are connecting to the Localhost in the browser, but  the website ends up looking not how it is supposed to look. The images aren't loaded in, and generally the css is missing. You can take a look at it in the picture:

[image: Example]

Does anyone know why that is happening?

Comment: Open the Dev Tools (F12) and reload. Find the network tab and the 404 errors.

Comment: I did that. I got a bunch of 404 errors for basically all components. For example: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Post the Index.cshtml and an exact dump of a 404 error.  Not many clairvoyants here.